# When will DevDemon's Campaigns module "URL Shortener" integration be ready?

Tags: devdemon

DevDemon's Campaigns module has a section within its Settings for URL Shorteners. When you try to set up a service, however, you get the message seen in the following screenshot.  Anyone know when this functionality will go live?

[image: Screenshot: Coming Soon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions like this are best submitted directly to the developer since they will be the best party to provide an answer for you.